# Empty list in navbar page when switching pages

Tags: blazor

Please see code below. I get 'name' sent from index.js every time when certain condition is met. Using 'name' value, I display or not display certain items on nav menu bar.

Problem is when I switch page (for eg, from index.razor to fetchdata), I want the list 'ListofItems' in navbar.razor page to become empty. And add only new names that are returned for the new page.

I tried this: ListofItems.clear() -> this clears list when switched pages but allows only one item to be added to ListOfItems at any point of time. I would get many. Thank you.

NavMenu.razor:

```
      public string name { get; set; }
      List<string> ListofItems = new List<string>();

      protected override void OnInitialized()
       {
            AddData.OnNameSent += HandleNameSent;  @* for passing name *@
        }

      private void HandleNameSent(string name)
        {
           ListofItems.Add(name);
           StateHasChanged();
           @* ListofItems.clear() *@
        }

        public void Dispose()
       {
            AddData.OnNameSent -= HandleNameSent;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [NavigationManager.LocationChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.navigationmanager.locationchanged?view=aspnetcore-7.0) event to detect when the user switches page.

```cs
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

...

@code {
    List<string> ListofItems = new List<string>();

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        AddData.OnNameSent += HandleNameSent;
        NavigationManager.LocationChanged += OnLocationChanged;
    }

    private void HandleNameSent(string name)
    {
        ListofItems.Add(name);
        StateHasChanged();
    }
    
    private void OnLocationChanged(object sender, LocationChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListofItems.Clear();
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        AddData.OnNameSent -= HandleNameSent;
        NavigationManager.LocationChanged -= OnLocationChanged;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, do you have any advice on this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74007336/onlocationchanged-should-be-called-before-parsing . Thank you.